# Problems with FCGI request from the client side in rust

Tags: php, rust, fastcgi

I'm currently working with some colleagues on a small personal project which requires a FastCGI request, for now this is the code we have:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() {
    // here we create the request body, which should be sent in the FCGI_STDIN record
    let data = "foo=bar";

    // here we define the constants that FastCGI needs
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;
    const FCGI_STDERR: u8       = 7;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    // here we connect to the socket
    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    // we send the record FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST
    let requestId: u16 = 1;

    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;

    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];

    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    // send the FCGI_PARAMS

    let param1_name = b"SCRIPT_FILENAME";
    let param1_value = b"/var/www/public/index.php";
    let lengths1 = [ param1_name.len() as u8, param1_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params1_len: u16 = (param1_name.len() + param1_value.len() + lengths1.len()) as u16;

    let param2_name = b"REQUEST_METHOD";
    let param2_value = b"POST";
    let lengths2 = [ param2_name.len() as u8, param2_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params2_len: u16 = (param2_name.len() + param2_value.len() + lengths2.len()) as u16;

    let param3_name = b"CONTENT_LENGTH";
    let content = data.len().to_string();
    let param3_value = content.as_bytes();
    let lengths3 = [ param3_name.len() as u8, param3_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params3_len: u16 = (param3_name.len() + param3_value.len() + lengths3.len()) as u16;

    let param4_name = b"CONTENT_TYPE";
    let param4_value = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".as_bytes();
    let lengths4 = [ param4_name.len() as u8, param4_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params4_len: u16 = (param4_name.len() + param4_value.len() + lengths4.len()) as u16;

    let params_len = params1_len + params2_len + params3_len + params4_len;

    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];

    /*
     * here we write the parameters SCRIPT_FILENAME, REQUEST_METHOD, CONTENT_LENGTH and CONTENT_TYPE (which are sent correctly)
     */
    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths1).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths2).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths3).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param3_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param3_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths4).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param4_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param4_value).unwrap();

    /*
     * From here we start working with FCGI_STDIN. 
     * 
     * Frst we calculate the length of the content and then we send the FCGI_STDIN record together with the request body
     */
    let contentLength = data.as_bytes().len();

    let requestHeader = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDIN,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (contentLength >> 8) as u8, (contentLength & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all (&requestHeader).unwrap();

    socket.write_all (&data.as_bytes()).unwrap();


    let mut stdout: String = String::new();

    // get the response
    let requestHeader = vec![
        FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDOUT,
        (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    loop {
        // read the response header
        let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];

        socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();

        if responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDOUT && responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDERR{

            if responseHeader[1] == FCGI_END_REQUEST {
                println!("FCGI_END_REQUEST: {:?}", responseHeader);
                break;
            } else {
                println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: {}", responseHeader[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        // read the body
        let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);

        let mut responseBody = vec![0; responseLength];

        socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody).unwrap();

        stdout.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&responseBody));

        // read the padding
        let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[6] as usize];

        socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();
    }
    
    println!("Output: {}", stdout)
}
```

That code sends an FCGI request to a php file, which has this content:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

And when I run the rust code I get this output:

```
FCGI_END_REQUEST: [1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0]
Output: X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.13
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

array(0) {
}
```

Everything works fine except that PHP does not receive the request body, it seems to me that the value of `$_POST` should not be empty. So I guess the problem is with the `FCGI_STDIN` record. I have looked in the [FastCGI specification](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eyandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html), and the only related thing I have found is that if the value of CONTENT_LENGTH is different from the bytes received by FCGI_STDIN the connection would be closed, but even if i just send the `FCGI_STDIN` record and don't send the request body i don't see anything happen

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't PHP receive the request body?

### Update

When I run the code that was left in the answer to this question, that is, this code:

```
$pl = file_get_contents('php://input');

var_dump($pl);
```

When executing that PHP file from my rust code I get an empty string, I get this:

```
 string(0) ""
```

So what is the problem in my rust code? Why is the data not sent correctly?

Comment: I was not able to find any thing wrong with your code. I tried messing around with values and see what happened, but to no avail. I suppose there is a record that needs to be sent that you are missing. I started to look at other implementations to see if I could see the difference, but it is starting to get late here, so I have gave up looking for answers. I think you can check for how Nginx do it https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/bfc5b35827903a3c543b58e4562db8b62021c164/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c and see if there are any discrepancies with how you do it.

Comment: I've tried looking there, but can't find anything wrong. I have also looked at the fastcgi specification. And clearly you can see that my code does exactly what the second example does: https://www.mit.edu/~yandros/doc/specs/fcgi-spec.html#SB. So I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: btw fcgi is not unicode aware, and because of that it may be that "foo=bar" isn't getting there, have you considered trying it with `let data = b"foo=bar"`

Comment: @AhmedMasud Yes, actually that's what I do when I send `data`, I send it as `data.as_bytes()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for I never used FastCGI but, I'm pretty confident about having a look in the payload :)

```
// returns json
$pl = file_get_contents('php://input');

var_dump($pl);
```

You can then store the results in an array to better handle them:

```
$params = json_decode($pl, true);
```

Hope it will be the answer you are looking for,
Best.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I already edited my question with more information about your code :D.